# Gyro not reading correct angles

Tags: gyroscope

I am new to raspberry pi. I am using below mentioned code to read gyro angles. When I read with inclinometer, angles are not showing correctly.

```
from L3GD20 import L3GD20
import time

# Communication object
s = L3GD20(busId = 1, slaveAddr = 0x6b, ifLog = False, 
ifWriteBlock=False)

# Preconfiguration
s.Set_PowerMode("Normal")
s.Set_FullScale_Value("250dps")
s.Set_AxisX_Enabled(True)
s.Set_AxisY_Enabled(True)
s.Set_AxisZ_Enabled(True)

# Print current configuration
s.Init()
s.Calibrate()


# Calculate angle
dt = 0.02
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
while 1==1:
    time.sleep(dt)
    dxyz = s.Get_CalOut_Value()
    x += dxyz[0]*dt;
    y += dxyz[1]*dt;
    z += dxyz[2]*dt;
print("{:7.2f} {:7.2f} {:7.2f}".format(x, y, z))
if(x>45 or x<-45 or y>45 or y<-45 or z>45 or z<-45):
print("Toppled")
```

Comment: Use text formatting and provide some of your debug output with a more verbose explanation.

Comment: _"angles are not showing correctly"_ is not a problem description. What would "correct" be? How do yours differ?

Comment: I have placed a compass with my Gyro. I am using ALtiMu 10 v4. The angle my code is showing differ from what compass is showing. I have stacked my gyro and compass at same level and move it together to read angles.

Comment: The compass is showing 60 degree and my angles are these
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.52    0.08   -0.45
   1.44    0.08   -0.45

Comment: "The angle my code is showing differ from what compass is showing" why would they be the same? gyro gives you a rate of change, and your summation will introduce errors, so you'd expect the change in one of the axes to be approximately equal to any change in the compass, but the others are not going to be related.

Comment: Yes I am looking for one angle to be same. Not even one angle is showing same as in compass.